# Formulario Bootstrap complicado! - Reducir espacio

Tags: bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy nuevo en tema de diseño web, buscando en la web me encontre con el framework bootstrap y me ha parecido super...pero le he hado para tratar de diseñar un formulario igual al de la imagen y no podido dar con la forma de hacerlo.

Con la ayuda de algunas personas de este foro pude alinear los dos cuadros de texto con Bootstrap, pero no logro hacer que este mas unidos para darle mayor uniformidad al formulario, como se podria lograr esto?

Ingreso de Pacientes
        
            
                
                    
                        Tipo de Indetificacion
                        
                            

                            
                        
                    
                    
                        Numero de Identificacion
                        
                            
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        Primer Nombre
                        
                            
                        
                    
                    
                        Segundo Nombre
                        
                            
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        Primer Apellido
                        
                            
                        
                    
                    
                        Segundo Apellido

                        
                            
                        
                    
                


                
                    
                        Sexo
                        
                            
                                Masculino
                                Femenino
                            
                        
                    
                    
                        Fecha de Nacimiento

                        
                            
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        Estado Civil
                        
                            
                                Soltero(a)
                                Casado(a)
                            
                        
                    
                    
                        Ocupacion
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                
                                
                                    
                                
                            
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        Direccion
                        
                            
                        
                    
                    
                        Telefono Fijo
                        
                            
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        Celuluar
                        
                            
                        
                    
                    
                        Email
                        
                            
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        Ciudad
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                
                                
                                    
                                
                            
                        
                    
                    
                        Departamento

                        
                            
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        Regimen
                        
                            

                            
                        
                    
                    
                        Tipo de Afiliado
                        
                            
                                Cotizante
                                Beneficiario
                                Adicional
                             
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        EPS
                        
                            

                            
                        
                    
                    
                        Rango
                        
                            
                                1
                                2
                                3
                                No Aplica
                            
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        
                            Enviar

```
</div>
```

Documento sin título

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Ingreso de Pacientes</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form id="form" class="form-horizontal "role="form">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-lg-5 control-label" name="nombre">Primer Nombre</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="text_nom1" id="text_nom1" required/>
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-lg-5 control-label">Segundo Nombre</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <input class="form-control"  name="text_nom2" id="text_nom2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">  
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-lg-5 control-label">Primer Apellido</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <input class="form-control"  name="text_ape1" id="text_ape1">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-lg-5 control-label">Segundo Apellido</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <input class="form-control"  name="text_ape2" id="text_ape2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="row"> 
                        <div class="form-group form-inline col-md-6">
                            <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-lg-5 control-label">Ciudad</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <input class="form-control" id="ejemplo_password_3" name="text_ciu" id="text_ciu">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                <input class="form-control" id="ejemplo_password_3" name="text_ciu" id="text_ciu">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-lg-5 control-label">Departamento</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <input class="form-control" id="ejemplo_password_3" name="text_dep" id="text_dep">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-2 text-center">
                            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                                <button type="button" id="btn_enviar" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Bienvenido, debería editar la pregunta agregando el código sobre el que has trabajado para poder orientarte. Mientras, básicamente necesita [Formularios en Horizontal](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) y [Columnas](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic) para armar esa estructura.

Comment: Hola Oscar ya añadi el Codigo. Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas entender como funcionan las columnas, como se anidan, y como se dan distintas dimensiones dependiendo de la anchura del navegador.

Estabas cerca de conseguirlo!

En cada columna puedes combinar los tamaños `col-xs-1/12`, `col-sm-1/12`, `col-md-1/12` y `col-lg-1/12` para lograr la estructura deseada.

En este caso particular sin entrar a fondo en modificar el `css` original de `bootstrap` para ajustar la separación entre elementos necesitarías algo así:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Ingreso de Pacientes</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form id="form" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-md-4 control-label" name="nombre">Primer Nombre</label>

                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input class="form-control" name="text_nom1" id="text_nom1" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 control-label">Segundo Nombre</label>

                        <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8">
                            <input class="form-control" name="text_nom2" id="text_nom2">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-md-4 control-label">Primer Apellido</label>

                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input class="form-control" name="text_ape1" id="text_ape1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 control-label">Segundo Apellido</label>

                        <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8">
                            <input class="form-control" name="text_ape2" id="text_ape2">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-md-4 control-label">Ciudad</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="ejemplo_password_3" name="text_ciu" id="text_ciu">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-9 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="ejemplo_password_3" name="text_ciu" id="text_ciu">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="ejemplo_email_3" class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 control-label">Departamento</label>

                        <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8">
                            <input class="form-control" id="ejemplo_password_3" name="text_dep" id="text_dep">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-2 text-center">
                        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                            <button type="button" id="btn_enviar" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pero por defecto, `bootstrap` alinea las etiquetas `label` al margen derecho.

Con una línea `css` e indicando un `id` personalizado al formulario (*para que no afecte a otros formularios*) se soluciona.

```
#form label { text-align : left; }
```

Comment: Amigo Oscar....Gracias infinitas hay algun sitio que me puedas recomendar para entender de manera clara el tema da las Grid. Es decire cuando utiizo por ejemplo col-lg- o cuuando col-md en fin

Answer (score 3):

Te recomiendo echarle un ojo a http://bootsnipp.com/forms donde te ayuda a generar el `HTML` necesario mediante `drag and drop` de `controles`, basado en esta web tenemos lo siguiente (de manera vertical):

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Form Name</legend>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="text_nom1">Primer nombre</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="text_nom1" name="text_nom1" placeholder="Primer nombre" class="form-control input-md" type="text">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="text_nom2">Segundo nombre</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="text_nom2" name="text_nom2" placeholder="Segundo nombre" class="form-control input-md" type="text">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="text_ape1">Primer apellido</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="text_ape1" name="text_ape1" placeholder="Primer apellido" class="form-control input-md" type="text">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="text_ape2">Segundo apellido</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="text_ape2" name="text_ape2" placeholder="Segundo apellido" class="form-control input-md" type="text">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="text_ciu_nom">Ciudad nombre</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="text_ciu_nom" name="text_ciu_nom" placeholder="Ciudad nombre" class="form-control input-md" type="text">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="text_dep">Departamento</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="text_dep" name="text_dep" placeholder="Departamento" class="form-control input-md" type="text">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="text_ciu_cod">Ciudad Código</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="text_ciu_cod" name="text_ciu_cod" placeholder="Ciudad Código" class="form-control input-md" type="text">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="btn_enviar"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="btn_enviar" name="btn_enviar" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

También en http://bootsnipp.com/ encuentras diversos ejemplos basados en Bootstrap. Finalmente aqui tienes un par de buenos tutoriales explicado paso a paso:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/index.htm
- http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/

Aunque en inglés -> con un traductor la haces o dale a aprender el idioma en:

- http://www.memrise.com
- http://www.duolingo.com
- http://www.engvid.com

Espero te sea de utilidad :D

Comment: Amigo de gran ayuda tu valioso aporte. Gracias!!!

Comment: de nada brother, dale con todo el power 2.0!!! En especial en la documentación oficial :D

Answer (score 2):

bootstrap se basa en un diseño por columnas: en la siguiente url puedes encontrar la información para empezar http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

En resumen, tienes 12 columnas para extender el contenido de las páginas. Por lo que habría muchas formas de replicar el formulario que compartes. Por ejemplo una de las formas sería la siguiente:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/bootstrap.min.css">     
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
            <p>Primer Nombre</p>                
            <p>Primer Apellido</p>
            <p>Ciudad</p>
    </div>      
    <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="text"></input>             
            <input type="text"></input>
            <div>
                <input style="display:inline; width:60px" type="text" ></input>
                <input style="display:inline; width:60px" type="text" ></input>
            </div>
    </div>      
    <div class="col-xs-3">
            <p>Primer Nombre</p>                
            <p>Primer Apellido</p>
    </div>      
    <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="text"></input>             
            <input type="text"></input>
    </div>  
</body>
```

Nota que el total de las columnas con clase col-xs-3 suma 12 columnas, donde el número 3 indica la cantidad de columnas. Dado que col-xs-3 está 4 veces, ahí se suma el total de 12 columnas.

Lo importante de bootstrap es modificar la cantidad de columnas que un contenido usa dependiendo de las resoluciones de las pantallas, por lo que te recomiendo que uses la documentación en el link que te comparto para que aprendas a usar adecuadamente la herramienta.

Saludos.